# Laravel Model Query - can use "Models:all()" but "where/whereRaw" return no data

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model

at Laravel PHP,

I try to query to Models to get json Data, what's strange here, i just can only use query like `Models:all()` but cant use where.

## For The First Query

i can use below query :

**`$models = SadaqahHistory::all();`**

it will return results :

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success, user=25, date from=2019-07-01, end date=2019-07-31",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 372,
            "month": 7,
            "year": 2019,
            "name": null,
            "point_total": 198,
            "total": 4580,
            "sadaqah_date": "2019-07-05 00:00:00",
            "status": 0,
            "is_dzikir": 0,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user_id": 1034,
            "month": 7,
            "year": 2019,
            "name": null,
            "point_total": 2,
            "total": 46,
            "sadaqah_date": "2019-07-05 00:00:00",
            "status": 0,
            "is_dzikir": 0,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
...
```

### For The Second Query

i can't use below query, because will return null/no data :

**`$models = SadaqahHistory::where('user_id', $user->id)
          ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(sadaqah_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '$startDate' 
          AND '$endDate'")
          ->actived()
          ->orderBy('sadaqah_date', 'desc')
          ->get();`**

it will return no data / null :

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success, user=25, date from=2019-07-01, end date=2019-07-31",
    "data": []
}
```

===Edit, Add **`SadaqahHistory Model`** :

```
namespace App;
class SadaqahHistory extends BaseModel
{
    const STATUS_CONVERT_FROM_POINT = 1;
    protected $table = 'sadaqah_history';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'name',
        'point_total',
        'total',
        'sadaqah_date',
        'status',
        'is_dzikir',
        'foundation_donate_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'foundation_donate_id',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by'
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'status' => 'int',
        'is_dzikir' => 'int',
        'point_total' => 'int',
        'total' => 'int',
        'user_id' => 'int',
        'foundation_donate_id' => 'int',
    ];
    public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
    public function foundationDonate()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\FoundationDonate', 'id', 'foundation_donate_id');
    }
```

Any Idea Why, my second Model Query wont work ?

Comment: the first thought is that your second SQL statement does not return any results. Are you sure about that?

Comment: yes, 2nd SQL statement not return any result...

Comment: so the problem is there, not in laravel

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro what's the problem ?

Comment: The error is in the SQL, not in laravel or PHP. For example the whereRaw clause does not have sense.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro how i can print my query to log/command line ?

Comment: you should tell us what you wanna get from that query.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro this is identic SQL query = `SELECT * FROM sadaqah_history WHERE user_id = 25 AND sadaqah_date BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30'`

Comment: look your code: you did not use between anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this SQL you need:

```
SELECT * FROM sadaqah_history WHERE user_id = 25 AND sadaqah_date BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30'
```

And if `$startDate` and `$endDate` do have the YYYY-MM-DD format, you should use this:

```
$models = SadaqahHistory::where('user_id', $user->id)
      ->whereRaw("sadaqah_date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'")
      ->orderBy('sadaqah_date', 'desc')
      ->get();
```

Comment: Hi Thanks :D, now it's works. but i see you remove `->actived()`, if i add it it wont show results. so, what's the purpose of it ?

Comment: actived() is not a native Eloquent command. I guess you copied your example from somewhere where the had a function inside the Model like this:    func actived() { return $this->where('active',true);} or something like that.